# R: Help using dummyVars and adding back into data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, r-caret

I have a data.frame of 373127 obs. of 193 variables. Some variables are factors which I want to use dummyVars() to separate each factor into its own column. I then want to merge the separate dummy variable columns back into my original data.frame, so I thought I could do the whole thing with apply, but something is not working and I can't figure out what it is.
Sample:

```
dat_final <- apply(dummies.var1, 1, function(x) {
  dummies.var1 <- dummyVars(~ dat1$factor.var1 -1, data = dat1)
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using a function that is not in the base packages you need to execute (and post the `library` call) the loading of the package. To wit: `?dummyVars
No documentation for ‘dummyVars’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??dummyVars’`. It's also the case that defining dummy variables is usually not needed since all self-respecting regression functions will do all the needed construction automatically for factor variables.
`

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following that will create a new df, trsf, but you could always reassign back to the original df:

```
library(caret)

customers <- data.frame(
    id=c(10,20,30,40,50),
    gender=c('male','female','female','male','female'),
    mood=c('happy','sad','happy','sad','happy'),
    outcome=c(1,1,0,0,0))

# dummify the data
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = customers)
trsf <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = customers))
print(trsf)
```

[See more here](https://amunategui.github.io/dummyVar-Walkthrough/)

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is .... Don't do that. It's almost never necessary.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I would argue that it does address the problem at the level of sophistication presented in the question. (And I did earlier leave comments that requested better documentation regarding the function and the rational for not needing to use it.) If someone is doing something that is unnecessary then I think they should be told not to do it.

Comment: @BondedDust In that case, would it be a good idea to copy/paste your earlier comments into your answer... and then possibly expand on your initial thoughts?

Comment: If you actually know anything about R and how it handles discrete variable then you are welcome to post a better answer. If the only thing you are doing is attempting to enforce some SO guideline about "tone" of answers in the absence of any domain knowledge, then I think you should retract your delete vote.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
# Example data
df = data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS, each = 3), y = rnorm(78))

df = cbind(df, model.matrix(~df$x - 1))
```

However, as pointed out by @user30257 it is hard to see why you want to do it. In general, modeling tools in R don't need dummy vars, but deal with factors directly.

Answer (score 0):

Creating dummy variables can be very important in feature selection, which it sounds like the original poster was doing.

For instance, suppose you have a feature that contains duplicated information (i.e., one of its levels corresponds to something measured elsewhere).  You can determine this is the case very simply by comparing the dummy variables for these features using a variety of dissimilarity measures.

My preference is to use:

sparse.model.matrix and
cBind